# Not able to run an OpenGL program

Tags: opengl

I am trying to run an OpenGL program. When I compile that program terminal, it shows an error:

```
fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory  #include <GL/glut.h>
```

When I try to install freeglut, I got another error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev libgi-mesa-dev libglui-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev
[sudo] password for yash: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgi-mesa-dev
E: Unable to locate package libglui-mesa-dev
```

Please help me to figure this out.

Comment: I've not heard of a program called "opneGL".  Is the source available on github?

Comment: You appear to be mistyping the relevant package names - for example AFAIK it should be `libglu1-mesa-dev` (with digit `1`) **not** `libglui-mesa-dev` (letter `i`)

Comment: »» GL/glut.h: No such file «« : Install glut → `sudo apt install freeglut3-dev` https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/freeglut3-dev

Answer (score 3):

You seem to mistaking the numeral '1' for 'i'.  E.g. the packages you need are: `libg1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev` NOT `libgi-mesa-dev libglui-mesa-dev`

Try the 'apt-get' or 'apt install' again with the correctly spelled package names.

Comment: Probably also `libgl1-mesa-dev` instead of `libg1-mesa-dev`?